# How do i send multi dimentional array from browser url and recieve in php API

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to access the indexed multi dimensional array sent from my app.for the test purpose i am sending request by url.

`xyz/?array1[0][id]=2&array1[0][value]=400`

this is how i am receiving and echoing.

```
  ?php
  $price[][]=$_REQUEST['array1'];
  echo $price[0]['id'];
  echo $price[0]['value'];
```

but i am getting `array1 as $price[0]['id']` and `$price[0]['value']` empty.
also in error log its showing id and value not defined. Any help would be great.

Comment: did you try `echo $_REQUEST['array1[0][id]'];`?

Comment: ya it didnt display anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just don't need the [][] after your $price.

```
$price=$_REQUEST['array1'];

echo $price[0]['id'];
echo $price[0]['value'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is the equivalent of

```
$price = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => $_REQUEST
    )
)
```

which means you need `$price[0][0]['id']['value']` instead

Comment: no its like `$price[0]['id']` and `$price[0]['value']`